# Can't set up WebStorm

Tags: java, 16.10, ide, intellij

Build `WS-163.9166.30`

WebStorm doesn't want to remember my JetBrains account license on 16.10. I unzipped it to `/opt`. It worked fine from `/opt` on 16.04

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Could not lock User prefs. Lock file access denied.
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.checkLockFile0ErrorCode(FileSystemPreferences.java:937)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.lockFile(FileSystemPreferences.java:925)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.sync(FileSystemPreferences.java:729)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.flush(FileSystemPreferences.java:824)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.syncWorld(FileSystemPreferences.java:464)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.access$1200(FileSystemPreferences.java:50)
    at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$3.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:432)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I tried `~` folder and other JetBrains products as well. Same story.

---

Also, JetBrains Toolbox is crashing after 5 seconds after launch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening a ticket with JetBrain's support, this is what helped me:

1. Open (or create) `webstorm64.vmoptions` file. If you can open
   WebStorm, you can go to **Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...**. If you
   can't, create a file named `webstorm64.vmoptions` in the config
   directory (usually `~/.WebStorm<version>`) and open it in a text
   editor.
2. Find (or create) a folder that you have full permissions to (e.g. `mkdir ~/.ws-prefs`)
3. Add the following line to the file:

   ```
   -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=absolute_path_to_prefs_folder
   ```

Save and restart WebStorm.

The issue happened again after upgrading WebStorm and a few reboots. This time, I've noticed that although it crushed during initialization after I've logged in to my JetBrains account, I was able to run WebStorm with a trial license. So I removed the entire configuration folder (`rm -rf ~/.WebStorm<version>`) and everything works again (for now...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with PyCharm. The following solved the problem for me:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 ~/.java/
sudo chown -R username:root ~/.java/
```

Just doing the first command wasn't enough.